# how to create query to monitoring how many minutes docker containers ran for a day

Tags: prometheus, grafana, prometheus-alertmanager, promql

I am trying to monitor docker containers, but I have problems when making a query to monitor how many minutes the container runs in a day

```
count(rate(container_last_seen{id=~"/docker/.*",instance=~"$node"}[1d]))
```

this is my query to show how many container run in a day, but i don't have idea for monitoring how many minutes container runs in a day

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add a brief description, code, errors of your search/research efforts as is suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know interval between data points for `container_last_seen` metric (it is known as `scrape_interval` and is usually configured in Prometheus config file), then the following query could be used for calculating the duration in seconds when container was running during the last day:

```
count_over_time(
  (changes(container_last_seen{id=~"/docker/.*",instance=~"$node"}[<3*scrape_interval>])>0)
  [1d:<3*scrape_interval>]
)*<3*scrape_interval>
```

For example, if `scrape_interval` equals to `10s`, then the query will look like:

```
count_over_time(
  (changes(container_last_seen{id=~"/docker/.*",instance=~"$node"}[30s])>0)
  [1d:30s]
)*30
```

This query uses [PromQL subqueries](https://medium.com/@valyala/prometheus-subqueries-in-victoriametrics-9b1492b720b3) for calculating the number `30s` intervals when `container_last_seen` time series had at least a single change.